# How to get all inputs for specific partition before map is executed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have following code:

```
partitions = 5
stitching_result = sc.\
    parallelize(probes_combination, partitions).\
    map(lambda l: stitch_images_pair(project, l)).\
    collect()
```

How I can get have callback function that will get **all** inputs for specific partition and will be executed before `map(lambda l: stitch_images_pair(project, l))` part ?

In my case it should run 5 times - ones for each partition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=mappartitions#pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions):

```python
def func(iterator):
    print("hello world")
    return iterator

stitching_result = sc.\
    parallelize(a, partitions).\
    mapPartitions(func, True).\
    map(lambda l: stitch_images_pair(project, l)).\
    collect()
```

prints five times `hello world` before executing `stitch_images_pair`.

When using the iterator inside `func` the iterator should be materialized into a list and a new iterator should be returned. The following code prints the number of rows within each partition:

```python
def func(iterator):
    data = list(iterator)
    print(len(data))
    return iter(data)
```